# Able to set and get cookie data despite blocking at browser level

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, asp-classic

I don't know why this is happening and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong but I have this code on an ASP classic page:

```
Response.Cookies("msg") = "Welcome"
Response.Write(request.Cookies("msg"))
```

And the page is displaying the message even though cookies are disabled by the browser. In Chrome for example, an icon indicating the "Cookie were prevented" appears. In "Settings > All cookies and site data", there is no cookie for the current site. I also checked the "Local Storage" folder on my hard drive where Chrome stores the data.

How is the page able to display the message if there is no evidence of a cookie?

Comment: I've tried also. I works for other pages . If you request cookie on the other pages there will not be any data. but the page where you are assigning the cookie gives "welcome" result. So I am still waiting for the result

Answer (score 0):

The answer of why this is happen is simpler and resides in the internals of ASP.
It's not really intuitive but what happens in the code above is that when you do:

`Response.Cookies("msg") = "Welcome";`

This cookie will be available to you in the context of this request but the browser will never save it.

So when you do the Response.Write what you are seeing is not the cookie that came from the browser but the one you just set.

In other words, you are not really setting up a cookie in the browser.